# Android cannot zoom in webview pdf from google pdf preview

Tags: java, android

my Webview load this url :
`https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AXv1bsjNMqX9oMvNndgNOQwrQAkzD4Pi/preview`

I have put my code like this :

```
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
        view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        view.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        view.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        view.clearCache(true);
        view.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        view.loadUrl("https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AXv1bsjNMqX9oMvNndgNOQwrQAkzD4Pi/preview");
```

but I still cannot zoom in the webview.

Comment: See this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setSupportZoom(boolean)

Comment: I added      ```view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);``` but still canot zoom the webview that loaded this pdf link